# can i apply quota on non partitioned /home drive RHEL7

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos7, rhel7, quota

I am having one RHEL 7 installed machine with following xfs partitions.

1. /
2. /swap
3. /boot

i did not create /home drive while creating partitions.

now i want to apply quota and not able to fine entries for '/home' drive in fstab file.

/home is resides in / (root) directory

please guide me how can i apply quota.

Aneesh

Comment: You would need to create a new partition, mount the partition to a temporary directory, copy the home directory to the temporary directory, amend fstab to reflect the new dedicated home partition and then reboot. You would then be able to set the quotas as required.

Comment: If you're using BTRFS, you can make /home a subvolume, which would allow you to mount it as its own subtree without affecting your partition structure. However, chances are you're using XFS, which is the CentOS 7 default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it states in RHEL 7 documentation (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disk-quotas.html) Disk Quotas are enabled on a filesystem, not on a folder inside a filesystem.

So, if you want quotas on only /home, then it needs to be its own partition/filesystem. If you want to avoid showing /home is fstab, but still have quotas, then you need to enable quota on the partition that contains it (/ in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using following link 
https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=557